# Transparent color works on the simulator but becomes black on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image, transparency

I am trying to draw an image that has some transparent regions. 
I load the image using

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testimage.png"];
```

and draw it using

```
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
```

The UIView on which I draw the image is not opaque (and it has a transparent background color).

The problem is that everything works fine on the simulator, but when I run the app on my iPhone the transparent color becomes black! Can anyone pinpoint my error?

Comment: Well, I have now tried another transparent test image that actually works fine on my iPhone! The image that displays incorrectly on iPhone was made transparent by irfanView. It looks transparent in Mac's cover flow, but I guess the iPhone does not accept all kinds of png:s....

Comment: How did you apply transparent to your image using irfanView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer to this problem is the .PNG format you are saving your image with. If you save as PNG-8, you will run into this problem more often that not, since it only supports 1 transparent color. If you open your .PNG file and then re-save it as a 24-bit format, you will gain genuine transparency.

Reference [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3736509) for discussion and clarification.

- EDIT: Just to be clear, .PNG does not have an 'alpha channel', so Chris' answer is misleading. Just be sure to save in 24-bit format with transparency enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today with a picture of mine. I've created the picture my self in GraphicConverter.

My solution was to add an alpha channel to the picture. I did this with GraphicConverter using the command found in Picture => Alpha Channel => Create Alpha Channel with transparency . It could be that the command has a different name for you as I use the app with a german language setting.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by loading it into colorsync and then saving it.